# Вопрос про Winium + Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins

Вопрос 1: Я запускаю тесты на виртуалке. Чтобы тесты проходили на них нужно смотреть - т.е. подключиться по виртуалке и развернуть окно. 
Как мне обмануть систему, и сделать так чтобы виртуалка постоянно думала что на нее смотрят?

Вопрос 2: Я залил тесты на Jenkins, они также запускаются и работают если на них смотреть. 
Но тут встал вопрос, в том что не работает java.awt.Robot - можно ли сделать чтобы он работал, или как заменить его действия? 
Robot нужен - чтобы нажать Enter, и водить/нажимать мышью.

Comment: некоторая полезная информация: https://habrahabr.ru/company/2gis/blog/263347/ (раздел Continuous Integration для Winium.Desktop-тестов)

Comment: @AlexChermenin, смотрел не понял про autologon. 
Касательно активности - виртуалка всегда активна, все параметры засыпания отключены(на ней гоняются selenium(браузерные) тесты)

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sysinternals/autologon.aspx

Comment: @AlexChermenin, Ну тут сказано касательного входа в систему, но виртуалка никуда не выходит, и логиниться постоянно не надо.